# Check If test-path Value is and then run, otherwise Test-path other value and run

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, system-administration

**My actual file configuration:**
clustername=GLA-CLU2

fswmain=\DC01\SQL-FSW1

fswdr=\DC01\SQL-FSW2

**My actual script:**

```html
### BEGIN OF Passing as Variables, the configuration values separated with '=' and Retrieved from the indicated TXT file:
Get-Content '.\FSW_pathConf.txt' | Foreach-Object {
   $Vconfvalue = $_.Split('=')
   New-Variable -Name $Vconfvalue[0] -Value $Vconfvalue[1] }
### END OF Passing values as Variables
### Testing Each Path defined into configuration file
$currentfsw = Get-clusterresource -cluster $clustername | where-object {$_.ResourceType -like "File Share Witness"} | get-clusterparameter -Name "sharepath" | Select Value
Write-Host "`r"
Write-Host "the current file share witness configuration On Cluster: '$($Clustername)' is: '$($currentfsw)' " 

if($currentfsw -is "$fswmain") {Test-Path -Path "$fswmain" -IsValid}
#if $fswmain is valid then return "OK,current fsw is working" and stop this script here
#If not $currentfsw is no valid then run the command below to swith to $fswdr
else{Set-ClusterQuorum -Cluster $Clustername -NodeAndFileShareMajority "$fswdr"}

#Then, only if $currentfsw is not equal to $fswmain
if($currentfsw -is "$fswdr") { Test-Path -Path "$fswdr" -IsValid}
#if $fswdr is valid then return "OK,current fsw is working" and stop this script here
#If not run the command below to switch to $fswmain
else{Set-ClusterQuorum -Cluster $Clustername -NodeAndFileShareMajority "$fswmain" }
```

**What I would like to do Achieve and WHich I am struggling with:**

if $fswmain is valid then return "OK,current fsw is working" and stop this script here

If not $currentfsw is no valid then run the command below to swith to $fswdr

Then, only if $currentfsw is not equal to $fswmain

if $fswdr is valid then return "OK,current fsw is working" and stop this script here

If not run the command below to switch to $fswmain

Any could bring some help here ? I am quite new with powershell and sysadmin

Thank you.

Comment: Generally, for which PowerShell version do you need it? Is v2.0 -v4.0 really necessary? Why not v5.1? Secondly, What is really the problem and what is your error message you get? Do you just need to know how an if-statement works?

Comment: Hi,
any version,2,3,4 as it running at least on windows server 2016(updated regularly)
could you help with If-statements? or try/catch? 
thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, i would need help with If-statement...for achieving it

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code skeleton below. This kind of code structure is actually well documented online. Any question you have should be answered there. I would suggest to go step by step and not try to run all possible options at once.

```
try {
  $pathExists = "C:\..\.."
  $pathNonExists = "C:\..\"
  if (Test-Path -Path $pathExists) {
    <Enter you code>
  }
  elseif (Test-Path -path $pathNonExists) {
    <Enter your code>
  }
  else {
    <Enter your code when all other options fails>
  }
}
catch {
  <Code when an error is thrown in your try block>
}
```

Comment: still can't make it with